# SQLite3 insertion into foreign key table doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, flask

I have an SQLite3 database running on a Python Flask server. I am trying to insert values into foreign key database but the values for the foreign key are set at Null.

In my Flask application.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from cs50 import SQL


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQL("sqlite:///test.db")

db.execute("CREATE TABLE 'people' ('id' integer, 'name' varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY(id))")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE 'friendships' (person_id INTEGER,'id' smallint, 'friends' boolean, FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id))")
```

At some point in the code I want to insert a 'friendship' into the referenced database, assuming I have two people with ids 1 and 2 in the 'people' table. Therefore, I run the code:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO friendships (person_id, id, friends) VALUES (1, 2, 1)")
```

This leaves me with a null value for this inserted row in the person_id field, and have no clue why it has happened. I'm also unable to find anything on similar problems online, so I would really appreciate any help.

Edit:
The code works on itself but I tried to insert an input from a non-existent form input value of person_id from the client-side to the server. This resulted in null values being submitted to the server, consequently ending up in the database.

Comment: Thank you, I edited to change the table name to what it should be

Comment: Your code works fine in SQLite: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=20ddb87840430396c7943ccf8f0ac78c

Comment: Thank you for this, it made me realise I made a mistake getting the person_id that I inserted in the last line from a post form on the website. I used request.form.get("person_id") but without that form input this of course results in the submission of a Null value to the server.